# How to fire a click event on Ember.View at a given position

Tags: testing, ember.js

For a testing purpose, I need to trigger a click event on a view and check if the mouse position is sent correctly to the callback.

I can trigger the event with :

```js
view.fire('click');
```

but how can I add the (x,y) coordinate of the mouse ?

With jquery one would do something like :

```js
var event = $.Event('click');
event.clientX = 100;
event.clientY = 50;
$('div').trigger(event);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just pass the event as argument, see http://jsfiddle.net/pangratz666/8nRRE/:

```js
var view = Ember.View.create({
    click: function(evt) {
        console.log('clicked on view at %@/%@'.fmt(evt.clientX, evt.clientY));
    }
});

var event = $.Event('click');
event.clientX = 100;
event.clientY = 50;

view.fire('click', event);​
```

All paramaters to `fire` are passed to the triggered event, see [evented.js](https://github.com/emberjs/ember.js/blob/master/packages/ember-runtime/lib/mixins/evented.js#L19-21).